# Chrome & Safari Error::Not allowed to load local resource: file:///D:/CSS/Style.css

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari

When I access my aspx page in chrome or safari it shows this error in console

> Not allowed to load local resource: file:///D:/CSS/Style.css

Everything works fine in IE and FF.

I use an external CSS which is linked in aspx page via

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="file:///D:/CSS/Style.css" type="text/css" />
```

I have tried all the combination of "/" & "\" slashes..

Whether I am giving file path in wrong manner or its any security exception in these browsers(I am logged in as administrator)...
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How about 2 `/`'s instead of 3

Comment: i hav already tried..but dint work

Answer (score 31):

You wont be able to access a local resource from your aspx page (web server). Have you tried a relative path from your aspx page to your css file like so...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/CSS/Style.css" type="text/css" />
```

The above assumes that you have a folder called `CSS` in the root of your website like this:

```
http://www.website.com/CSS/Style.css
```

Comment: that works but what about when I am forced to use local resource, actually I am in that situation now.

Comment: This relative URL may work for `.css.` It does not work for a background image referenced within a css background property. However, I could use an option on the develop menu to provide access to local resources. (See answer below.)

Answer (score 21):

It is today possible to configure Safari to access local files.

> - By default Safari doesn't allow access to local files.
> - To enable this
>     option: First you need to enable the develop menu.
> - Click on the
>     Develop menu Select Disable Local File Restrictions.

Source: http://ccm.net/faq/36342-safari-how-to-enable-local-file-access

Answer (score 8):

The solution is already answered here above (long ago).

But the implicit question "why does it work in FF and IE but not in Chrome and Safari" is found in the error text "Not allowed to load local resource": Chrome and Safari seem to use a more strict implementation of sandboxing (for security reasons) than the other two (at this time 2011).

This applies for local access. In a (normal) server environment (apache ...) the file would simply not have been found.

Comment: I only found this error by using Developer Tools in Chrome to see the message. I think this message should display in the browser, not buried in Developer Tools.

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is old but here is what I found.
It doesn't work when I link it this way(with `/` before `css/style.css`on the `href` attribute.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/CSS/Style.css" type="text/css" />
```

However, when I removed `/` I'm able to link properly with the css file
It should be like this(without `/`).

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="CSS/Style.css" type="text/css" />
```

This was giving me trouble on my project.
Hope it will help somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem. I provided relative path this resolved the issue

Before path was : c:\images\test\someimage.jpg
Updated to : ~images\test
After this I am able to view the images