# "Not allowed to load local resource" for coffee-script.js in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, coffeescript

There are alternatives such as put is online or use Firefox do debug,,
but I want to know if there's a method to load that `.js` lib on Chrome.

Comment: Possible duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074680/chrome-safari-errornot-allowed-to-load-local-resource-file-d-css-style

Comment: Could you post your code that imports the coffee-script.js library.

Comment: I mixed different situations up and made mistakes. Here's what I want to ask now. I ran a `node` process to serve a page which refers a 'coffee-script.js' file on another domain. While the `.js` was on my laptop and I use `"file:/home/chen/code/home/git/docview/libs/coffee-script.js"` to refer it, it gives out thie `Error`. And the source:  https://gist.github.com/2374764

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem:

```
<script src='file:/home/chen/code/home/git/docview/libs/coffee-script.js'></script>
```

Why:

```
"Only local script and and object resources are loaded"
```

Solution:
You need to include the coffee-script.js file in the package folder and access it from there.

Source: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/contentSecurityPolicy.html#H2-0

Comment: Could you give a simple demo please, for how can I solve this problem for this case?

Comment: All you need to do is include the coffee-script.js file inside your script folder for your google chrome extension. Then have the src attribute reference the file using a relative location. Example: script src="/libs/coffee-script.js"

Comment: But here I'm using Node to handle the URL of the request, is there still a relative location here?