CSS - how to load a custom local font on OSX
I have a local webserver, and I would like to load a local custom font that is not on my project folder
I have checked some tutorials, but for a reason I do not know, I do not manage to load the custom font
Here is what I have done so far
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Font test</title>
</head>
<style>

@font-face
{
font-family: 'TestFont';
src: local('/Users/gomu/Font/testBold.otf');
}

.fontTest
{
font-family: "TestFont";
}
</style>
<body>

<span class="fontTest">Font no jutsu!</span>

</body>
</html>

I have also tried other solutions like
src: local('file:/Users/gomu/Font/testBold.otf');

src: url('file:/Users/gomu/Font/testBold.otf');

But it does not work
I have also disabled the local file restrictions on Safari, but it still does not work.
What I am missing there?
I am currently working on MAC OS Sonoma and can use Safari and Chrome
For your information, "testBold.otf" works if it hosted on a server, but here my goal is to load it locally from my computer
Otherwise, maybe I need to put in the system font folder? (is there something specific to do about that)
Thank you in advance

local only takes a font name, not a file system path. And src: src isn't a thing; it's either src: local() or src: url().

You can't direct a web browser to load a font from a local path (or any file from a local path) – that'd be a security nightmare.
You'll have to put that font where your server can find it (e.g. in your project folder), and refer to it with a path that server can serve.

This question is similar to: @Font-face not working on mobile. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@C3roe Thank you very much for your answer, I edited my message, indeed I tried src: url(), it is a wrong copy/paste on my side, my bad.
For the local part, I understand I need to put a font name, but what are the steps so my custom font is taken into account? I guess if I just put local("testFont"), it needs to be integrated in the OS, right?

@RoyBogado Thank you for your answer, I checked your link, and the difference with my question is that I want to load the font locally outside of the project folder (it is specified in my question)

@AKX it seems you can by disabling some security on the settings, I read it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47458780

@HadoMonkey This honestly begs the question: why can't you put the file where it can be found, so you don't need to mess with that setting?

Anyway, the file:// URL should have three slashes (url('file:///Users/gomu/Font/testBold.otf')).

@AKX the aim is to connect to my webpage (hosted on a webhost) from several computers that will use a personal font that I do not want to be hosted on the webhost server

You have to host the font on a webserver where others can get the font. URLs in CSS are from the browser's perspective, so you can't use an absolute path to the filesystem (unless you're the only one accessing your webserver). You can package webfonts directly in your website/app if you meant to do that.

@HadoMonkey Will you be able to configure all of these computers accessing your page to allow local files, and will all of them have the font in the exact same directory? If so, this might work with the correct URL (see my comment above) – otherwise, I'd like to understand why the font can't be hosted where the page is.

@AKX I tried with the syntax you gave and I have this error message on Chrome
"Not allowed to load local resource:", I tried to disable all the securities, but nothing
I guess my only solution is to put the file in the system directly
To answer your other questions, yes all the computer (actually one for now) will be set to allow local files, and I will do something dynamic to load the font from the right folder
For the hosting part, it is just that that for now I prefer it does not go on any webhost server

Right. Since, as said, you can't refer to local files from remote origins due to security reasons, you'll just need to use a local(...) source for the font and have it installed on the machine(s).

@AKX Thank you for your answer, I have finally managed to do it for chrome here my post about it , seems there is no real solution for Safari to have the font locally

Make sure your "testbold.otf" file is in a directory within your webserver's root.
/your webserver root/
 /fonts/
  testbold.otf
 /your project/
  index.html
  .
  .
  .
  other files

After this update the CSS using the updated source url.

Thank you for your help, actually, I wanted to load the font locally, I managed to do it, you can see my post about it

I hope I understood correctly.
Since you mentioned that the fonts were not saved anywhere in the project, I used an external font. However, you could create a folder in your project and place the fonts inside it, allowing you to access them by referencing those fonts, which is a better solution.
In any case, there are three methods for foreign fonts, and I used Google Fonts.
All methods have been written and commented on so that you can study them more easily.
1- import
2- font-face
3- link


<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title>Font test</title>

  <!-- The third method: link 
  The third method is to use their links. I got it from Google Fonts. It definitely has to be in the head element.
  -->

 <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@200..700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<style>
  /* The first method: import */

  /* @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@200..700&display=swap'); */


  /* The second method: font-face */

  /* @font-face {
    font-family: 'TestFont';
    src: url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@200..700&display=swap');
    
  } 
  */

  .fontTest {
    font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
  }
</style>

<body>

  <span class="fontTest">Font no juts!</span>

</body>

</html>



You can also refer to the link above for more information on the mentioned topics:
enter link description here
I also added a folder named Fonts to my project and placed my downloaded fonts inside it and referenced them:


<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title>Font test</title>

</head>
<style>
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'TestFont';
    src: url('./font/Digi\ Sarvenaz.ttf');

  }


  .fontTest {
    font-family: "TestFont";
    font-size: 30px;
  }
</style>

<body>

  <span class="fontTest">Font no jutsu!</span>

</body>

</html>



I hope you have received my response.

thank you very much for the detailed answer, actually my need was to load a custom font installed in OSX system, I have finally managed to do it for chrome, here my post about it

I finally managed to display a custom font from the system (in Chrome)
What I was missing is that I needed to install the font in the system
Here are the steps to do it (on Sonoma) :

Open Font Book.app (you can find it on the Applications folder)

Choose "File" then "Add Fonts to Current User"

From there you will be able to add your font and install it in the system

Here is the official installation link (on the top left, you can choose your OSX version)
Install custom fonts on MacOSX


To finish here is the working code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Font test</title>
</head>
<style>

.fontTest
{
font-family: "TestFont";
}
</style>
<body>

<span class="fontTest">Font no jutsu!</span>

</body>
</html>

For information it works only on Chrome
For Safari users, it does not work due to security reason, here is a post about it
Hope it can help
PS: if someone has a solution for Safari, I will be glad to hear it
